# segmentation fault core dump in kruskal's algorithm

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, coredump

```
#include<stdio.h>

int find( int, int parent[10] );

int uni( int, int, int parent[10] );

int main()
{
    int i, j, k, a, b, u, v, n, ne = 1;
    int min, mincost = 0, cost[9][9], parent[9];
    printf( "\n\tImplementation of Kruskal's algorithm\n" );
    printf( "\nEnter the no. of vertices:" );
    scanf( "%d", &n );
    printf( "\nEnter the cost matrix:\n" );

    for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 1; j <= n; j++ )
        {
            printf( "Enter the cost of the edge(%d,%d)=", i, j );
            scanf( "%d", &cost[i][j] );

            if ( cost[i][j] == 0 )
            {
                cost[i][j] = 999;
            }
        }
    }

    printf( "The edges of Minimum Cost Spanning Tree are\n" );

    while ( ne < n )
    {
        for ( i = 1, min = 999; i <= n; i++ )
        {
            for ( j = 1; j <= n; j++ )
            {
                if ( cost[i][j] < min )
                {
                    min = cost[i][j];
                    a = u = i;
                    b = v = j;
                }
            }
        }

        u = find( u, parent );
        v = find( v, parent );

        if ( uni( u, v, parent ) == 1 )
        {
            printf( "%d edge (%d,%d) =%d\n", ne++, a, b, min );
            mincost += min;
        }

        cost[a][b] = cost[b][a] = 999;
    }

    printf( "\n\tMinimum cost = %d\n", mincost );

}

int uni( int i, int j, int parent[10] )
{
    if ( i != j )
    {
        parent[j] = i;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int find( int i, int parent[10] )
{
    while ( parent[i] )
    {
        i = parent[i];
    }

    return i;
}
```

It is not able to calculate u,v,uni... i am able to enter the values but i am getting a message segmentation fault (core dumped). i guess there is some problem with the function find and uni(may be in passing of the array parent)..

Comment: Do you know where the error occurs ?

Comment: And that's it, on your part? No running of the debugger, not even `printf()`s added to check what's going on, or at which *specific* values the program fails? No checking of `scanf()`s return values, no mirroring of what the program has read? No `assert()`s?

Comment: All code not checking scanf results should be auto-rejected with an appropriate message by stackoverflow. :-)

Comment: Also, 'int i, j, k, a, b, u, v, n, ne = 1;'.  Debug-slave commands are bad enough, but making it more difficult with single-letter var names is worse:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without trying to decipher what the code is actually about (single-letter variables, zero comments, no link to this "Kruskal's algorithm" or anything), and in addition to what I already wrote in my comment about adding `printf()`s to log intermediate values, checking `scanf()` return codes, mirroring user input back at the user, and sprinkling your code with `assert()`s...

`int parent[9]` is declared, but not initialized. `find()` uses the (uninitialized) contents. Undefined behaviour right there.

Various "fishy" details, like `main()` declaring `parent[9]` and `cost[9][9]`, but the functions declaring `parent[10]`. You also let the user enter the number of vertices, but happily *assume* that it won't be more than 9 when you use that number as upper loop bound. If any of your assumptions on the amount of storage provided doesn't hold, you're looking at out-of-bounds accesses.

At this point of the code review I'd toss down the code printout on the desk, and give you one of **those** long, hard stares...

Comment: thanks everyone its solved.. the problem was in passing the parent array with parent[10] and not initialising it..